# VBA: UsedRange Does not update correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem updating UsedRange every time I'm using it. I have this in my code:

```
Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
LastRow = Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

This is to check the the last row used in a particular work sheet. Now, it works and outputs the correct integer when you run it for the first time, but does not update if you remove rows from the column that has the highest amount of rows. The thing is, it DOES update if you add more rows into that particular column.

Here is my actual code:

```
Sub CMPGN_MCRO()

    Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange.
    LastRow = Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim RangeString As String
    Worksheets("Campaign").Select
    Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
    RangeString = Selection.Address

    Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
    RangeString = RangeString & ":" & Selection.Address 'Selects all the data in Campaign Worksheet.

    Dim C As Range
    i = 2
    For Each C In Worksheets("Campaign").Range(RangeString).Cells
      If Mid(C.Value, 6, 2) = "AC" Then
      Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i) = C.Value 'Echo out all the filtered data and output it to another worksheet.
      i = i + 1
    End If
    Next
MsgBox (LastRow)
End Sub
```

PS: I used MsgBox to echo out the integer that the usedRange produces.

Comment: VB.NET Tag removed. VB.NET <> VBA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try combining the UsedRange command with this:

```
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

The code SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) refers to the last used cell on the worksheet. In Excel, the similar command is {Ctrl End}.

In your code:

```
Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
LastRow = Sheets("Campaign").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

A thing to note is that sometimes just deleting the data (Del key) is not enough. Try actually deleting the cells ({Ctrl -}  or {Right click Delete}).

Another code that works, unless your worksheet is filled to the last row:

```
LastRow = cells(Sheets("Campaign").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row,1).offset(1,0).end(xlUp).row
```

What it does: Find the last cell from cell A1, then down one to be sure we are in an empty cell, then use ctrl-up to find the last cell filled with data. A bit messy, but works, even if there are some not properly deleted cells in column A.

Comment: Does not work for me, I deleted all the data in the campaign worksheet and it still echo out the older row count which is 179.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, dumb questions: how did you delete the data? Are you sure you have deleted them all? Try manually deleting all the cells, and run the code again. Only asking because it works properly for me, so I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ctrl A + Delete, that's what I did.

Comment: bah. Just for the sake of science, could you Ctrl A, Ctrl - (or right click, delete) and run again? also, another way would be something like this: `range("A1048576").End(xlUp).row`, but this is not fancy.

Comment: PS: If I do try to populate the worksheet and and more rows lets say for example, 190, it echos the 190 which is correct, it overrides the older value which is 179. but if I remove columns, it does not update.

Comment: Wow, seriously? it worked when I did Ctr A, Ctr -. Thanks! Can you explain to me what does this line of code do? .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row You might want to edit it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I'll also add another method, and edit the answer in a minute.

Comment: @Vacip: note that SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastRow) and End(xlUp) get you the last visible cell - so don't necessarily work the way you want when data is filtered or rows hidden.

Comment: @vacip your second method works great for me for finding the last non-empty cell in a column. I can't understand why the other obvious methods like `.Columns(1).End(xlDown)` and `.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` don't work as expected, but this does. Thanks.