# how to select a cell after a block of non-contiguous data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have below table

[image: tablexample]

I'm trying to paste data into cell D7 so the edge of the current box.

I tried using

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 1).Select
```

Comment: Have a look at **CurrentRegion** property on the Range object

Comment: Is A1:C6 a table (Ribbon > Insert > Table)?

Comment: My code should be working, now. I've edited it too many times. Sorry.

Comment: I added a P.S. to my answer. Very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

It is an Excel table so you can offset using the dimensions of the table Range, and resize to the one cell.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddressOfCell()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1").Range
        Debug.Print .Offset(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Credit to @Chronocidal for a much nicer:

```
Debug.Print .Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Address
```

Comment: Additionally I recommend [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) which is a nice resource to learn about how to handle tables.

Comment: @ QHarr `.DataBodyRange` should be `.Range` otherwise it will not recognize a possible result row. `.Range` represents the whole table, while `.DataBodyRange` only represents the data part without header/result rows.

Comment: Because `Range.Cells` allows you to specify Cells *outside* the range, you can just use `Debug.Print .Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Address` within the `With`

Comment: @Chronocidal Very nice!

Comment: thanks for responding here. Going to try above, but it wont be in table format

Comment: No worries. You should edit your question to make that clear. Any reason why you can't make it table format? It might make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:
This method will work regardless of whether the range is a table object or not.

```
Sub FindLastCell()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").CurrentRegion
Debug.Print rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1).Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you stated that UsedRange isn't reliable, wouldn't you think that SpecialCells would be unreliable, too? I'll add a P.S. to my answer.

Comment: You are correct. It does suffer from the same limitation! The underlying code goes back to the .UsedRange. Let's see if I can improve on the answer.

Comment: Found a new method that will get the last cell in the CurrentRegion. Thanks for the keen eye @VBasic2008!

Comment: Nice, but you still have "C1" in it, but if there would be data to the right or to the bottom, this might be the best way to go.

Comment: True. The answer is meant as an example, but you need to provide some starting point for the range under any circumstances if there is other data on the sheet.

Comment: If there is a line with no data (empty cells), it will fail. I know that it's not contiguous then, but my code still prevails. But don't delete it, it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Select
```

Comment: It will fail if the last cell is an empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

## After Used Range

**Just use this in your code:**

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells
  ActiveSheet.Cells(.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row + 1, _
      .Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column + 1).Select
End With
```

**To explain:**

```
Sub AfterUsedRange()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim LastCol As Integer
  With ActiveSheet.Cells
    'Find the LAST real row
    LastRow = .Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    ' Find the LAST real column
    LastCol = .Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
  End With
  ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol + 1).Select
End Sub
```

**To use it in a macro:**

```
Sub AfterUsedRange()
  Cells(.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row + 1, _
      .Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column + 1).Select
End Sub
```

or you can redecorate:

```
Sub AfterUsedRange()
  Cells(.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row, _
      .Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column).Offset(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

## P.S.

**To prove the rumors that the 'UsedRange' and 'SpecialCells' functions at least are NOT reliable if not unusable** are actually a **fact**

Referring to the line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 1).Select
```

opposed to my redecorated line of code (the first in the Answer)

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row, _
    .Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column).Offset(1, 1).Select
```

Let us call the first line: **SpecialCellsCode**.
Let us call the second line: **MyCode**.

The following table shows a simple self-explaining scenario.

```
  A  B  C  D
1 1  1  1
2    2  2
3       3  y
4          x
```

Let us call the 'intersection' of the first line and the first column **after** the 'UsedRange': **AfterUsedRangeAddress**.

Now, when opening the worksheet. **MyCode** **correctly** calculates that the **AfterUsedRangeAddress** is `D4` and selects it (x) and so does the **SpecialCellsCode**. When we delete the value 3 in Column '`C`', **MyCode** **correctly** calculates that the **AfterUsedRangeAddress** is `D3` and selects it (y), **but** the **SpecialCellsCode** **incorrectly** still calculates `D4` and selects that one (x).

To conclude, the SpecialCellsCode is **at least unreliable, if not unusable**.

The idea to even think about such a test and to further investigate was taken from the question [VBA: UsedRange Does not update correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30524093/vba-usedrange-does-not-update-correctly).

Comment: this one is interesting as above is not a table. going to try in my workbook now

Comment: Though it is true that the .UsedRange object isn't 100% error free, this method won't actually return the cell you highlighted. It will simply provide a Range of the current region and offset it.

Comment: @ rohrl77: You're absolutely right, therefore I corrected the code. Sorry for the inconvenience.